# How to make all the elements/balls from list detect walls with raycast (as in Swipe Dots)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game in Unity similar to Swipe Dots https://www.addictinggames.com/puzzle/swipe-dots

I managed to make the movement and the wall detection with raycast, but it works correctly only if the list contains one ball. However, in "GetDistance" method i've tried to make every ball in the list detect walls and be able to move within the walls in acordance with the number and grouping of the balls, like in Swipe Dots.

The problem is that as balls are being added to the list, raycasting  only works for the last (newest) element/ball in the list.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code, also attached an image [Current wall behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk93W.png)

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Layer Mask")]
    public LayerMask environmentLayer;

    [Header("Player Speed")]
    public float playerSpeed = 15f;

    public bool Moving, canMoveU, canMoveD, canMoveL, canMoveR;

    private Vector3 playerDirection;

    private float distanceToMove;

    public List<Transform> dots = new List<Transform>();

    private bool canAdd;



    private void Update()
    {
        CheckEnvironmentCollision();

        if (!Moving)
        {
            if (canMoveU)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    playerDirection = Vector3.forward;
                    GetDistance();
                    SoundManager.s_Instance.PlaySwipeSFX();
                    Moving = true;
                }
            }

            if (canMoveD)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                {
                    playerDirection = Vector3.back;
                    GetDistance();
                    SoundManager.s_Instance.PlaySwipeSFX();
                    Moving = true;
                }
            }

            if (canMoveL)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                {
                    playerDirection = Vector3.left;
                    GetDistance();
                    SoundManager.s_Instance.PlaySwipeSFX();
                    Moving = true;
                }
            }

            if (canMoveR)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                {
                    playerDirection = Vector3.right;
                    GetDistance();
                    SoundManager.s_Instance.PlaySwipeSFX();
                    Moving = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Moving)
        {
            float step = playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (playerDirection.z == 1)
            {
                Vector3 targetDestination = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, distanceToMove);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetDestination, step);

                if (transform.position == targetDestination)
                    Moving = false;
            }

            if (playerDirection.z == -1)
            {
                Vector3 targetDestination = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, distanceToMove);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetDestination, step);

                if (transform.position == targetDestination)
                    Moving = false;
            }

            if (playerDirection.x == -1)
            {
                Vector3 targetDestination = new Vector3(distanceToMove, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetDestination, step);

                if (transform.position == targetDestination)
                    Moving = false;
            }

            if (playerDirection.x == 1)
            {
                Vector3 targetDestination = new Vector3(distanceToMove, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetDestination, step);

                if (transform.position == targetDestination)
                    Moving = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckEnvironmentCollision()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, 1f, environmentLayer))
            canMoveU = false;
        else
            canMoveU = true;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.back, 1f, environmentLayer))
            canMoveD = false;
        else
            canMoveD = true;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.left, 1f, environmentLayer))
            canMoveL = false;
        else
            canMoveL = true;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.right, 1f, environmentLayer))
            canMoveR = false;
        else
            canMoveR = true;
    }


    private void GetDistance()
    {
        foreach (Transform dot in dots)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray directionRay = new Ray(dot.position, playerDirection);

            if (Physics.Raycast(directionRay, out hit, environmentLayer))
            {
                if (playerDirection.z == 1)
                    distanceToMove = transform.position.z + hit.distance - 0.5f;

                if (playerDirection.z == -1)
                    distanceToMove = transform.position.z - hit.distance + 0.5f;

                if (playerDirection.x == -1)
                    distanceToMove = transform.position.x - hit.distance + 0.5f;

                if (playerDirection.x == 1)
                    distanceToMove = transform.position.x + hit.distance - 0.5f;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddDotsToList(Transform dot)
    {
        dots.Add(dot);
        canAdd = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just keep a note of where dots are and attach or grab them accordingly

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.